# How to add a static content in a specific drupal page something like like using {% if is_front %} {% endif %} to add it in the home page

Tags: drupal

I am new to drupal and I tried to add a simple image as static in the html.html.twig page.
To display this image in the home page only I added this condition

```
{% if is_front %}
  {% endif %}
```

What is the condition to add it in another specific page example /contact/

I tried this code inside the page but it does not work, should I wrap it with some codes?

```
if(drupal_valid_path('contacts') == 1) //this exists
{
    print_r('Exists!');
}
```

Please help! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mixing twig with a drupal 7 function. I suppose anyway you're on D8/D9.

I also suppose the "contacts" page is a node. If it is somethings else - e.g. a view page - instead of checking for the node, you may have to check the route.

There are various approach, two possible would be:

- A hook preprocess where you load the node if exists

```
function hook_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
$variables['node'] = $node;
}
}
```

And the in the twig check the id of the node is the right one

- override the html.html.twig for the specific node, e.g. `html--node--10.html.twig`. In this case I'd suggest not to duplicate all the content of the base html.html.twig, but to use the [embed](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html) tag to override only the appropriate block.